# Eclipse RCP CSS pack() does not consider new font

Tags: css, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I work on a RCP-application and use the eclipse-css-feature too change the overall font of the application. But when used, the table-elements in the main-perspective does not adapt to the changes. In `createPartControl(Composite)` the table is filled with content and `TableColumn.pack()` is called on each one. Before I changed the overall font to Verdana 9px columns always were large enough to hold their content, e.g. "My very long text that is long". Now, however, the columns only display "My very long text that i...". Re-setting the content of the table (clear, fill and `pack()`) during the `setFocus()`-function seems to be working, but it also is a pretty bad workaround. Also, this does not solve the problem that I have to wait for the first click to do this.

How do I get my application to `pack()` table-columns properly on startup?

This is my css:

```
* {
    font: Verdana 8px;
    background-color: White;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the CSS styles are not applied until the `SWT.Skin` event is generated after the controls are created.

So you need to run your `pack` after that event. One way to do that is to use `Display.asyncExec` to run your pack code after the `createPartControl` has completed. The `asyncExec` `Runnable` should then run after the `SWT.Skin`.

Alternatively you can get the CSS styling engine and force the styling to happen. In a 3.x compatibility view/editor use:

```
IStylingEngine engine = getSite().getService(IStylingEngine.class);

engine.style(control);
```